# I am encountering a race condition with my current synchronized block

Tags: java, synchronization, race-condition

I'm a novice and have been struggling for some time to wrap my head around synchronization particularly with a synchronized block implementation.  Firstly yes this is for a class, I don't want a solution as I need to learn this stuff. I'm instead curious about roughly what issues are present with my current approach so I can better understand what I'm doing wrong and work my way to a solution.

I'm attempting to create a FIFO Blocking queue for a task executer. Restrictions on implementation include No use of semaphores, locks, or java synchronization mechanisms.  Implementation of synchronization must be done through primitive object monitors, and synchronized block.  The initial code had a built in race condition that I need to resolve under these restrictions.  Currently I have managed to limit the occurrence, but the race condition still occurs approximately every 10,000 tasks.  Essentially some tasks are being started twice. Included is a portion of the current implementation, it handles taking tasks from the queue for execution by a thread.

[This is a portion of the current implementation that handles taking tasks from the buffer for execution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbJQL.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I managed to sort out the issue by moving my task result, nextout, count, and return into the synchronized(notfull) block.  Unsure if this would be the best solution in a normal situation but under the current constraints it has fixed my issue with the race condition.

[Task taking implementation with changes made.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3pYB.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).